# ISC DHCP (Infoblox) takes 30+ seconds to respond to DISCOVERS

Tags: unix, dhcp, dhcp-server, isc-dhcp

Client's DISCOVER packets reach the Infoblox DHCP server through DHCP relays, but Infoblox doesn't seem to be responding.

I checked the pcap taken from the DHCP server, I can see there is 3 DISCOVERS from the Client (via Relay), Infoblox DHCP provides an offer only after the 3rd Discover.

But in the syslog, we do not see multiple DHCP discovers, just a DISCOVER message and an OFFER can be seen in right after to that. Not sure if the packets are being dropped in NIC level.

Checked the ping before the offer settings, it is just 1.

It especially happens when the server touches 30% of CPU usage, but 30% of CPU would not kill the server though.

Once we restart the DHCP service, it would start to respond normally to the DHCP DISCOVERS.

Not sure how to proceed, any help would be really appreciated.